# CSqlDataProvider in Yii1.1 giving wrong data even if it has working query in it

Tags: php, mysql, yii1.x

The below code is for a search function, and the query I am getting in `$sql` is working if I try in MySQL or phpMyAdmin, but `$dataProvider->getData();` is empty here, and that too in few cases because in some cases it gives result and in few cases, it doesn't.

```
$count=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,
    array(
        'pagination'=>FALSE,
        'params'=>$sqlParam
        )
    );

$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,
    array(
        'totalItemCount'=>count($count->getData()),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->getModule('search')->searchPageSize,
            ),
        'params'=>$sqlParam
        )
    );
$dataProvider->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)?

Comment your 'totalItemCount' parameter and try again.